# nut-client - Не работает NOTIFYCMD

Tags: linux, debian

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело?

Есть настроенный nut-server, который успешно подключается к UPS, есть настроенный nut-client который мониторит UPS и в случае проблем в syslog выдаёт сообщения:

> - Nov 2 20:13:12 localhost upsmon[1428]: UPS ippon3000@localhost on battery
> - Nov 2 20:13:37 localhost upsmon[1428]: UPS ippon3000@localhost on line power

однако никак не хочет выполнять мой скрипт.

```
> /etc/nut/upsmon.conf
NOTIFYCMD /etc/nut/notify.sh

NOTIFYFLAG ONLINE SYSLOG+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG ONBATT SYSLOG+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG LOWBATT SYSLOG+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG FSD SYSLOG+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG COMMOK SYSLOG+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG COMMBAD SYSLOG+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG SHUTDOWN SYSLOG+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG REPLBATT SYSLOG+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG NOCOMM SYSLOG+EXEC
NOTIFYFLAG NOPARENT SYSLOG+EXEC

> /etc/nut/notify.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "$UPSNAME - $NOTIFYTYPE - $1\n" » /root/log.log
```

Права на файлы notify.sh и log.log - 0777. Если вызвать скрипт вручную, то он срабатывает, а автоматически вообще ничего не происходит.

```
root@orangepione:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
root@orangepione:~# uname -m
armv7l
root@orangepione:~# uname -a
Linux orangepione 5.8.16-sunxi #20.08.14 SMP Tue Oct 20 22:15:32 CEST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@orangepione:~# apt-cache policy nut
nut:
  Установлен: 2.7.4-8
  Кандидат:   2.7.4-8
  Таблица версий:
 *** 2.7.4-8 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: права на `/etc/nut/notify.sh` какие? а на запись в файл `/root/log.log`? попробуй писать куда-нить в `/tmp` вместо `/root`...

Comment: Он ведь не от рута запущен? Если это верно, тогда не сто́ит ему писать в какой-то файл в домашнем каталоге рута.

Comment: А если всё же от рута (что не есть хорошо, IMHO), то убедитесь, что у вас в скрипте не кавычка-ёлочка, а два знака "больше". Хотя, если вручную срабатывает, то должно быть всё корректно.

Comment: @Fat-Zer права стоят на всё что связано с nut - 777 ( поставил от безысходности ), в том числе на содержимое /etc/nut/* и /root/log.log.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev вначале было запущено от root, потом от nut:nut, но опять таки файл /root/log.log имеет права 777.
Кавычка разумеется нормальная :)

Comment: Единственное за что я могу зацепиться, это способ подключения монитора к серверу: `MONITOR ippon3000@localhost 0 upsmon pass master`, в частности `0`, но у меня ситуация такая, что UPS фактически может работать от батареи бесконечно долго и мне ничего выключать не нужно, и тем более нельзя выключать сам UPS, и судя по документации `0` как раз для этого и предназначен.

Comment: гм... вроде всё выглядит так что должно работать... а если скормить `-D` `upsmon`'у при запуске в логах ничего не проясняется?

Comment: @Fat-Zer в syslog? ничего криминального не нашёл.

Comment: @Dragon_Knight ну так что, что файл. Попробуйте от другого юзера (не от рута и не от группы-владельца рутового каталога) в этот файл что-нибудь выдать, убедитесь: permission denied.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev запускаю от юзера nut - тоже самое.
В папку /tmp тоже ничего не пишет. На все конфиги и выполняемые файлы выставил nut:nut 0777

Comment: @Dragon_Knight, а может `upsmon`/`upsd`, в качестве меры безопасности, отказывается читать конфиги/исполнять файлы из-за того, что запись в них разрешена всем? хотя скорей всего в этом случае он бы об этом в логах ныл...

Comment: @Dragon_Knight может быть private tmp же. Сделайте ему каталог с файлом, которые (и файл, и каталог) будут принадлежать ему. Где-нибудь в /var/cache, например. Не поможет - смотрите strace'ом

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev не разобрался как тут помечать правильные ответы, но Вы были правы. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

По совету @AlexanderProkoshev нашёл причину: нехватка прав.
Создал папку /var/cache/nut с правами nut:nut, перенёс туда скрипт и указал писать файл log.log в эту же папку и всё заработало.